# Filemaker GetAsNumber on ExecuteSQL

Tags: filemaker

I have a calculation for a field like this:

```
GetAsNumber(
    ExecuteSQL ( 
        "SELECT nb FROM something WHERE value = ?" ;
        "" ;
        "" ;
        amount
    )
)
```

Everything works fine as long as the returned number is single-digit. But when the SQL statement returns for example "12", then the number I get from the GetAsNumber function is suddenly 1212 instead of 12.

As I understand it, this has somehow to do with the format in which SQL results are returned, it says so in the documentation ("FileMaker Pro returns date, time, and number data in Unicode/SQL format, not in the locale of the operating system or the file.").

But I guess there must be a way to format back the result so it can be converted to a number.

Comment: I believe you are misrepresenting the situation. When the result of `ExecuteSQL()` is `"12"`, the result of `GetAsNumber()` will be `12`. However, if you have **two** records that satisfy the `WHERE` clause, then the result of `ExecuteSQL()` might be `"12¶12"`, which `GetAsNumber()` will return as `1212`. Overall, it's not clear what are you trying to accomplish here. The `ExecuteSQL()` function returns a text array that may contain multiple values; it makes no sense to convert it to a number as a whole.

Comment: Thank you, that's probably the information I was missing: `The ExecuteSQL() function returns a text array that may contain multiple values`. I think I was fooled because a calculated field (which I set up to test this) with the ExecuteSQL showed "12", but that's probably only the way the field renders the output, even if it's an array.

Comment: If you have a calculation field using the `ExecuteSQL()` function (which I would not recommend), make sure the result type is Text. And make it tall enough to show multiple rows (add a scroll bar, if necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution comes from by michael.hor257k's comment on my question:

ExecuteSQL returns an array (I wasn't aware of it, it's also not specified in the documentation where it says: "Data type returned: text"). So my problem had nothing to do with double digits (I guess I should have run more tests), but with the sql statement returning more than one result.

As in my case multiple results are always the same, I could alter my calculation in this way:

```
GetValue(
    ExecuteSQL ( 
        "SELECT nb FROM something WHERE value = ?" ;
        "" ;
        "" ;
        amount
    ) ;
    1
)
```

In this way I only retrieve the first result.

As michael.hor257k suggested in his comment, I could also restrict the SQL result to one row.

```
ExecuteSQL ( 
    "SELECT nb FROM something WHERE value = ? FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY" ;
    "" ;
    "" ;
    amount
)
```

Comment: I used the term "array", but FM does not have an array data type. The result is indeed text, formatted as CSV (when using the default separators).

Comment: BTW, you can use `GROUP BY` to remove duplicate values in the SQL query itself. Or `FETCH FIRST`, if you know there should be only one.

Comment: How can you be using `ExecuteSQL()` with SQLite?

Comment: @michael.hor257k You're right, I can't, my mind was somewhere else when I wrote this... (edited out in the answer now)

Comment: Ok, but you cannot use `LIMIT` in Filemaker SQL.

Comment: right. Edited :)